# Java Spring Boot won't pick up variable from application.yml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am working on an application that uses a variable that is declared in the application.yml file. In my application.yml file it is defined as so:

```
lwt:
  application:
    five-minute-jobs: ${ENABLE_FIVE_MINUTE_JOBS:true}
```

In my controller file it is declared this way but it is always returning `false` whenever I log it in in the console. Here is the shortened version:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;

public class EmailJobSchedulerController {

    @Value("${lwt.application.five-minute-jobs}")
    private boolean fiveMinuteJobsEnabled;
```

Am I declaring it correctly in the file? Been searching on other threads but haven't been able to find a clear answer for this. Thanks!

Comment: What are we doing with the dollar in the property in the application yml? are u trying to reference a system property?

Comment: Issue might be with your env variables ${ENABLE_FIVE_MINUTE_JOBS:true} the env might going as string value try with just give true value and test

Comment: the code snippet you have provide is correct for the logic you want to achieve. I've copied this code over to a small sample project and was able to get "true" back by default and then override the value to false by using an ENV var. Have you checked if you have that ENV var set on your local machine? If so, it would be override the value from the yml file.

Comment: You haven't shown how you're obtaining a copy of `EmailJobSchedulerController`. More generally, field injection is prone to all sorts of problems, and converting to constructor injection will _most likely_ show you exactly where this problem lies.

Comment: Did you declare a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer in your configuration class? If so don’t. In that case it will run into lifecycle issues since Sptring Boot provides a default one

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried with code below?

```
lwt:
  application:
    five-minute-jobs: true
```

Comment: That is factually the same as the code provided, only that the original code allows overriding the value through an environment variable.

Comment: I've added this into my example project on GitHub and it's working...
Check this out: https://github.com/DanielMichalski/spring-boot-rest-example/tree/feature/value-testing

Comment: I cannot do this due to it being an environment variable that gets overriden

Answer (score 2):

May be you are not setting the `env` variable correctly. Can you do the following in your main `@SpringBootApplication` class and tell me what it is printing?

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class AccessingDataJpaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(AccessingDataJpaApplication.class);
        System.out.println(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("ENABLE_FIVE_MINUTE_JOBS"));
        System.out.println(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("lwt.application.five-minute-jobs"));
    }

   }
```

Comment: They both return null

Comment: So none of them is getting used by spring boot and the default value for boolean is `fiveMinuteJobsEnabled` getting used. How are you running the application? Is it from IDE? And do you have an `application.properties` as well?

Answer (score 1):

@value annotation will get the value if it's under bean life cycle else you need to take from ConfigureEnviornment class, is below code is registered with bean ? I feel you might be missed adding @RestController on top of this class

```
 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
@RestController
 public class EmailJobSchedulerController {

@Value("${lwt.application.five-minute-jobs}")
private boolean fiveMinuteJobsEnabled;
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting, @RestController has already been declared on top of the class. Sorry I didn't include it in the post.

Comment: Okay might issue with primitive type can you Boolean as type ``@Value("${lwt.application.five-minute-jobs}")
    private Boolean fiveMinuteJobsEnabled;``

Comment: Issue might be with your env variables ``${ENABLE_FIVE_MINUTE_JOBS:true}`` the env might going as string value try with just give true value and test

Comment: I am passing in true and it still defaulting to false when I log it on the console