.yml file reference shows as null when called
I have a server-local.yml file which has a boolean flag with values with either true or false:
isFruitSweet: ${IS_FRUIT_SWEET:- true}

In the test, I am referring to the declarations as:
public boolean fruitFlagCheck()
  {
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    InputStream ymlReader = 
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("server- 
local1.yml");

    Map<String, Object> yamlMaps = yaml.load(ymlReader);

    Boolean fruitFlag = (Boolean) 
yamlMaps.get(System.getenv("IS_FRUIT_SWEET"));

    LOG.info("Value of Fruit Flag: " + fruitFlag);
    return fruitFlag;
  }

I even tried adding EVN Var in the Run Configuration of the Application to have the flag IS_FRUIT_SWEET as either true or false.
But each operation results in a value showing up as null. Any help is appreciated.
It should return the boolean flag value as true or false. But rather is always showing up as null.

I tried solutions from these as well to no luck:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72547261/getting-null-values-while-reading-application-yaml-file-in-java
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63198077/java-spring-boot-wont-pick-up-variable-from-application-yml

I'm not sure why you are using a variable ${IS_FRUIT_SWEET...} as value.
For such a simple use case you can just define
isFruitSweet: true

and request with
yamlMaps.get("isFruitSweet")

On https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml you can find some examples how to deal with yaml files in connextion with SnakeYAML.

Update: Modified the method which works for using the variable as isFruitSweet: true and is correctly identifying the yaml file as well. But since the variable IS_FRUIT_SWEET is utilized in pipeline as an Environment Variable, I have to use the IS_FRUIT_SWEET and this is now giving null value.
